# Change an element of a website using a script?

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, greasemonkey

**OBSERVED BEHAVIOR**

I am using a website that displays a location on the page.

Example: San Francisco, CA \ Orlando, FL \ etc.

Like the text in the above example the location is static 
and does not do anything.

[image: Static Location Text]

```
<span class="userinfo2015-basics-asl-location">Orlando, FL</span>
```

To bring more life to the page and add functionality to that location, I installed GreaseMonkey which allows a user to create scripts that modifies the functionality of a page. Unfortunately the script was outdated and didn't work. But the code seems to be on the right track.

```
var locE = document.getElementById('span.userinfo2015-basic-asl-location');
var location = locE.textContent;

var newSrc = "https://www.google.com/maps/place/"+location;
var link = document.createElement('a');
link.setAttribute("href",newSrc);
link.setAttribute("target","_blank");
link.innerHTML = location;
locE.parentNode.replaceChild(link,locE);
```

**EXPECTED BEHAVIOR**

The GreaseMonkey script would make the static location that you saw above into a link that redirects you to Google Maps.

**RELEVANT INFORMATION**

Using Greasemonkey Version 3.8

Using FireFox      Version 47.0

Comment: Recommend you read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for details on how to ask this type of question.  And welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: Not sure about what you are asking as major part of the question is covered with topic on greasemonkey instead of exact problem
By the way the span is using a class & you are doing doucment.getElementById,which is wrong.Also there is typo in class name.Check this jsfiddle and confirm if it s working fine

https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/a3o8Lyvn/

Comment: @user2181397 After reviewing your code and updating the GreaseMonkey script with your changes, it still doesn't work. I am going to do a little more research on GreaseMonkey to see why your code didn't solve my problem. Thank you very much for your assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work with a few changes:

1. It looks like you misspelled your class name.
2. You need to use `getElementsByClassName()[0]` to get an element by class name.

I had some trouble getting this to work in the snippet, but **I got it to work** in JSFiddle:

[JSFiddle: Span to Link](https://jsfiddle.net/Slulego/wbsq582f/)

Here's the modified JavaScript:

```
var locE = document.getElementsByClassName('userinfo2015-basics-asl-location')[0];
var location = locE.textContent;

var newSrc = "https://www.google.com/maps/place/" + location;
var link = document.createElement('a');
link.setAttribute("href", newSrc);
link.setAttribute("target", "_blank");
link.innerHTML = location;
locE.parentNode.replaceChild(link, locE);
```

Comment: After reviewing your code and updating the GreaseMonkey script with your changes, it still doesn't work. I am going to do a little more research on GreaseMonkey to see why your code didn't solve my problem. Thank you very much for your assistance.

Answer (score 1):

Some things to correct:

- To find the element you should in your case not use `getElementById`, as that would need an `id`. Instead use `querySelector`;
- the class name you specify is not the same as in the HTML code: `-basics-` has an `s` at the end;
- don't use `location` as a variable name, as that is a reserved property of the global object. Use something like `newLocation`;
- when adding a string to a URL, special characters (like `&`, `/` and `=`) should be escaped. You can use `encodeURIComponent` for that;
- not really an error, but it is better to assign text to `textContent` than to `innerHTML`, as it not really is HTML you are assigning.

```js
// use querySelector
var locE = document.querySelector('span.userinfo2015-basics-asl-location');
// don't use location as variable name.
var newLocation = locE.textContent; 
// use encodeURIComponent
var newSrc = "https://www.google.com/maps/place/"
          + encodeURIComponent(newLocation);
var link = document.createElement('a');
link.setAttribute("href",newSrc);
link.setAttribute("target","_blank");
link.textContent = newLocation; // use textContent
locE.parentNode.replaceChild(link,locE);
```

```html
<span class="userinfo2015-basics-asl-location">Orlando, FL</span>
```

Comment: After reviewing your code and updating the GreaseMonkey script with your changes, it still doesn't work. I am going to do a little more research on GreaseMonkey to see why your code didn't solve my problem. Thank you very much for your assistance.

Comment: Any errors in the console? If in Firefox open global console with `ctrl+j` and check for errors.

Comment: locE is undefined //
document.querySelector(...) is null// 
TypeError: target.tagName is undefined//
document.querySelector(...) is null// Location_to_Google_Maps.user.js:9:12

Comment: This means the `span` element is not found in your document. Can you make sure the spelling of the class name is exactly the same in the `querySelector` argument as in your HTML, and that it is a `span`? Did you provide a value for `@run-at` in the [meta block](https://wiki.greasespot.net/Metadata_Block)? If so, which value? What browser are you running on?

Comment: NB: I have GreaseMonkey running, and the above script works on my setup, so I really think you have a typo somewhere. Check the argument of `querySelector`. It should be as I put in my answer, and the `span` element must have exactly that same class (`userinfo2015-basics-asl-location`) or it will not work.